"Windows 64-bit" vs "Windows 64-bit (Modern)" in Delphi IDE Library Paths
I noticed in Delphi 12.1, that there's a "Windows 64-bit" and a "Windows 64-bit (Modern)" within the library paths

I tried searching for what it could be, but didn't find anything.
What is the difference between "Windows 64-bit" and "Windows 64-bit (Modern)"?
I'm not sure if "Windows 64-bit (Modern)" was available in previous Delphi versions or not, but this is the first time noticing "Windows 64-bit (Modern)".

And when selecting platforms to compile to, there's only "Windows 64-bit". So what the heck is "Windows 64-bit (Modern)"?

A quick Google search suggests that this is only related to the C++ compiler, not the Delphi compiler.

@AndreasRejbrand But it's listed under Delphi? Hold on. Let me update my question to show it under Delphi.

Section
<Platform Name="Win64x"> <Operation>1</Operation> </Platform> 
in .dproj files also related to this staff. I would like to remove it, but haven't a way...

Directly from Embarcadero:
"The Windows 64-bit Modern C++ toolchain (bcc64x) is an entirely new implementation of the Clang extensions and C++Buidler features with new, platform-standards technology. Besides, it is our recommended C++ toolchain for use.
It uses the LLVM libc++ STL, a custom C++ RTL, the Windows UCRT for the C runtime, and emits object files in COFF64 format with PDB debug info."
I think this entry should only appear in the configuration for C++, not Delphi.

Windows-64bit Modern platform needs to be added to Delphi packages (libraries) if you want to share those with C++ Builder and its new Modern toolchain.

Well it appears in Delphi configuration, but probably to compile packages that would be compatible with C++ Toolchain.
